# OnClickListener Not working when Edit Text is disabled

Tags: java, android

I have one edittext view in my android application. For free users, I want disable edittext view and when user tap on that, I want show toast.
I have managed disable edit by below code

```
text_status1.setEnabled(false);
```

But now I my `setOnClickListener` is also not working. anyone can please help me for make it working while edittext is disabled?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of `setEnabled` use `setFocusable` in this way :

```
  EditText some = mView.findViewById(R.id.some);
    some.setFocusable(false);
    some.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            System.out.println("your View got clicked");
        }
    });
```

By using setFocusable false the user can perform click on the view but he can't get the focus he needs to edit the editText